# stable and unstable limit cycles

Tags: dynamical-systems

Given a system $$\dot x = -y + xF(r), \ \dot y = x + y F(r) $$ where $F(r):= r^4-3r^2+1$.

I need to find out the stable and unstable limit cycle for the given system.

**My Approach**

I used the polar coordinates to reduce the system as $$\dot r = r(r^4-3r^2+1), \ \dot \theta =1$$

The reduced system has a unique critical point at origin since $\dot \theta \neq 0$.

So to find the stable and unstable limit points all I need to check is the sign of $\dot r$ in the annulus. I am not able to follow up from here.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $$ r^4-3r^2+1=0$$
gives two positive roots
$$ r_{1,2}=\sqrt{\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}}. $$
Then the equation becomes
$$ r'=r(r^2-r_1^2)(r^2-r_2^2). $$
and $$ x^2+y^2=r_{1,2}^2$$ are two solution curves. Consider the region
$$ R_k=\{r: r_k-\epsilon <r<r_k+\epsilon\}$$
for small $\epsilon>0$. Then on $r=r_1-\epsilon$, $r'<0$ and on $r=r_1+\epsilon$, $r'>0$ and hence $r=r_1$ is an unstable limit cycle. Similarly $r=r_2$ is another unstable limit cycle in $R_2$ too.
[image]

Comment: What about the unstable cycles?

Comment: Let me think for a while.

Comment: I am supposed to prove that there exists a unstable cycle in $1 \lt x^2 + y^2 \lt9$

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: What is $1<x^2+y^2<0$?

Comment: there is no 0. Unstable cycle in $1 \lt x^2+y^2 \lt 9$

Comment: Do we have a stable cycle in $0 < r < 1?$

Comment: Since $0<r_1<1$, so $r=r_1$ is an unstable limit cycle.

Comment: But the question asks to prove that it is a stable one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117397/discussion-between-atul-anurag-sharma-and-xpaul).

Comment: See the graph I added to the answer